# Display row where count(*) is zero using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need write a query to show all the records which are present in where condition and if that column does not have any value it should return as 0.

How can I write this query without using dual table?

```
SELECT city, count(city)
FROM Customers
where City IN ('ABCD','US' )
group by city;
```

**Input**

```
City 

US
```

**Output should be**

```
ABCD  0

US    1
```

Comment: Why can't you use dual?

Comment: i need to check for more than 100 value, so it won't be possible to write dual 100 times.

Comment: Where is the list of cities to check coming from then?

Comment: i will pass that as list of Input, and if data is not present, it should return 0.

Comment: Given in query itself, in table we are having value for US, but whenever i will check for other CITY, it should return that City name with count 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a collection and left outer join instead of `in()`:

```
select t.column_value as city, count(c.city) as city_count
from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('ABCD','US')) t
left join customers c
on c.city = t.column_value
group by t.column_value
order by city;

CITY       CITY_COUNT
---------- ----------
ABCD                0
US                  1
```

The `sys.odcivarchar2list` is a built-in collection type, and in this case it's initialised with your list of 2 or 100 or however many values to look for.

The `table()` is a table collection expression which expands the list into individual rows, one per list value. The result set from that has a single column you can refer to as `column_value`.

Those expanded rows can then be left-joined to your customers table for an aggregate count. Because of the outer join you will see zero reported for any values in the list which have no matches in the customers table.

Or you could use an XQuery sequence, but the list is a bit harder to construct:

```
select x.city, count(c.city) as city_count
from xmltable('"ABCD","US"' columns city varchar2(10) path '.') x
left join customers c
on c.city = x.city
group by x.city
order by city;

CITY       CITY_COUNT
---------- ----------
ABCD                0
US                  1
```

That can be useful if you are passed a single string containing the comma-separated values, rather than an actual list of values.